# How to change properties of a TlistBoxItem in a android app in runtime?

Tags: android, delphi, listbox, delphi-xe, listboxitem

In my program, i made a function which reads a xml of a blog and put the Titles in a `TListBox`. But i need to change some properties in `TListBoxItem`, like font, height and color, but it doesn't change.

How to set it in runtime ?

```
repeat
  Title := ANode.ChildNodes['title'].Text;
  Link := ANode.ChildNodes['link'].Text;
  Desc := ANode.ChildNodes['description'].Text;
  DataPub := ANode.ChildNodes['pubDate'].Text;
  SetLength(Vet_News, Pos + 1);
  Vet_Nesw[Pos] := '<h2>'+Title+'</h2>'+Desc;
  Itemx := TListBoxItem.Create(self);
  Itemx.Text := Title;
  Itemx.ItemData.Detail := DataPub;
  Itemx.ItemData.accessory := TListBoxItemData.TAccessory.aMore;
  Itemx.TextSettings.WordWrap := true;
  Itemx.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Darkorange;
  Itemx.Height := 65;
  Itemx.FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Darkorange; // i tried two ways to change the color
  lbNews.AddObject(Itemx); // lbnews is a Tlistbox 
  Inc(Pos);
  ANode := ANode.NextSibling;
until ANode = nil;
```

Comment: You probably need to change the style for the TListBox or the list box items.

Comment: Another idea ? Only in runtime i can't change the settings.

Comment: Via StyleLookup (for the item)? Change the style the item is using, or change the lookup to refer to a new style. Otherwise, can you expand your question, please?

Answer (score 0):

[Tested with Delphi-XE7]
At runtime, Listboxitems already have a calculated style stored in : `aListboxItem.StyledSettings`.
To change a setting at runtime, you first have to remove it from the list of styled settings.

For example, if you want to change the `FontColor`, first remove the styled fontcolor:

```
aListboxItem.StyledSettings := aListboxItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];
```

Then apply another one (let's say Green):

```
aListboxItem.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Green;
```

The `TStyledSetting` constants and corresponding `TTextSettings` properties are listed [here in Delphi's doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings).

Examples for changing styles at runtime can be found [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Setting_Text_Parameters_in_FireMonkey) and [there](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE8/en/FMXTFont_%28Delphi%29).

Nota Bene: `theListBox.Items[i]` gives access to item content, not the item itself.
To grab a ListboxItem as a control, and then act on its properties, you can use:

```
aListboxItem := theListBox.ListItems[i];
```

or

```
aListboxItem := theListBox.ItemByIndex(i);
```

Both giving exactly the same result, I cannot say if one is better.