# WordWrap for TListBoxItem

Tags: delphi, listbox, firemonkey, word-wrap

I'm making a RSS feed app with Delphi XE7 (Firemonkey) and the articles are displayed with a Listbox : (Text of ListBoxItem for titles and Details of ListBoxItem for articles). 
But as you can see in this screenshot:

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [evolutiongraph.fr](http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/13/Capture.jpg))</sub>

the articles are too long and do not come back to the line. The propertie WordWrap for ListBox doesn't exists.
So I was looking for a way to solve this problem and I didn't find.

Can you help me ? And if it's impossible to do that way, can you propose me another way to display articles ?
Thank you !

Comment: I Edited the screen. Humm...I Didn't know this property. Can you tell me more ? Or give me a link :)

Comment: @David prolly I overlooked it, then.

Answer (score 4):

### Using a `TListBox` (as you did) :

At runtime, `ListBoxItems` already have a calculated style stored in `aListBoxItem.StyledSettings`.
To change a setting at runtime, you first have to remove it from the list of styled settings.

For example, if you want to change the `FontColor`, first remove the 'styled' fontcolor:

```
aListboxItem.StyledSettings := aListboxItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];
```

Then apply another one:

```
aListboxItem.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Green;
```

The `WordWrap` property is defined in `TStyledSetting.Other`.
To change it:

```
aListboxItem.StyledSettings := aListboxItem.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Other];

aListboxItem.WordWrap := True;
```

The `TStyledSetting` constants and corresponding `TTextSettings` properties are listed [here in Delphi's doc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings).

**On accessing `TListBoxItem` properties :**
`theListBox.Items[i]` gives access to item content, not the item itself.
To grab a `ListboxItem` as a control, and then act on its properties, you can use:

```
aListboxItem := theListBox.ListItems[i];
```

or

```
aListboxItem := theListBox.ItemByIndex(i);
```

Both giving exactly the same result, I cannot say if one is better.

**On text height :**
Once the text is wrapped in the control, you will probably need to adjust the control's height to show the entire text.
This can be done `OnApplyStyleLookup` event, using a `TTextLayout` :

```
uses 
... ,FMX.TextLayout;

procedure TfrmForm1.ListBoxItem1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  myLayout: TTextLayout;
  i: integer;
  aPoint: TPointF;
begin

  myLayout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
  myLayout.BeginUpdate;

  // Setting the layout MaxSize
  aPoint.X := ListBoxItem1.Width;
  aPoint.Y := TfrmForm1.Height;
  myLayout.MaxSize := aPoint;

  myLayout.Text := ListBoxItem1.Text;
  myLayout.WordWrap := True ;
  myLayout.Font := ListBoxItem1.Font;
  myLayout.HorizontalAlign := ListBoxItem1.TextSettings.HorzAlign;
  myLayout.VerticalAlign := ListBoxItem1.TextSettings.VertAlign;
  myLayout.Padding := ListBoxItem1.Padding;
  // set other properties as needed

  myLayout.EndUpdate;

  ListBoxItem1.Height := Trunc(myLayout.TextHeight) + 3 ;

end;
```

Note that `MaxSize` is limitating. For example, `aPoint.Y` will limit the final TextHeight. 
You should set it large because, whatever `TextHeight` should be, if `myLayout.TextHeight` is larger than `myLayout.MaxSize.Y` then `myLayout.TextHeight` will be set to `myLayout.MaxSize.Y`. 
[Here's a list](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/FMX.TextLayout.TTextLayout_Properties) of `TTextLayout` properties.

**N.B.:** You may have to specify the font size at runtime before measuring the text height, or to set different from default at design time.
On my testing device (Samsung Note 2), the default font size is measured 14 ( `ListBoxItem1.Font.Size = 14` ) but it's rendered as 18. And it's not a scale issue.
Then, the calculation for `myLayout.TextHeight` is done with `Font.Size = 14` while the `ListBoxItem` will still render `Font.Size = 18`, still not fitting.
It can be useful to reset `Font.Size` just before layout calculations by adding :

```
ListBoxItem1.StyledSettings := ListBoxItem1.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.Size] ;
ListBoxItem1.Font.Size := ListBoxItem1.Font.Size ;
```

---

### Alternatively, you can use a `TListView` :

`TListView` is better suited for long lists and the `WordWrap` property can be set at design time.
To find it in the *Object Inspector* go to :

> ListView1 > ItemAppearanceObjects > ItemObjects > Text > WordWrap

Resizing will still be needed to fit the text height.

---

Examples of what can be done with ListBox and ListView in this CodeRage video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRj3qjUjBlc

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to help me, I really appreciate. I'm reading your answere and I'll try all that. Thanks again.

Comment: @user54517 : You're welcome. I just encountered the same issue few days ago and I managed to solve it. StackOverflow is SO useful for me, I really have to give back when I can. I would be pleased if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use ListBoxItem.WordWrap. More detail in site [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem.WordWrap)

Try write similar function:

```
for I:= 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Do
  ListBox1.Items[I].WordWrap := True;
```

Comment: As I said in my post, above, this property does not exists for the ListBox. I thought of a condition, but I don't know if it's correct : something like "If the length of the item is superior to the lenght of the screen, execute the WrapText fonction http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=WrapText  (WrapText(string, LengthOfTheItem - Sreensize)

Comment: It's not in the TListBox, it's in the TListBoxItem. Create each item in code and set it at creation time.

Comment: I do not create items manually, but dynamically : it's a RSS feed

Comment: Why does it matter where you create the items? Manually or at designtime? Why does that change anything?

Comment: Manually, when I put the ListBoxItem.TextSettings.WordWrap to True in the designer, it works perfectly. But when I do it with the code, it does not work.

Comment: See also related question: [How to change properties of a TlistBoxItem in a android app in runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062707/how-to-change-properties-of-a-tlistboxitem-in-a-android-app-in-runtime)

Comment: @user "It does not work" are the most useless 4 words in the history of problem description. We don't know what you did, we don't know what happened, we don't know how that failed to meet expections. It didn't work? So fix it.

Comment: Hum...how to explain clearly...When I add a ListBoxItem with the designer, and then put the WordWrap property to True, the WordWrap is activated : it WORKS : http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/16/Capture.jpg But, when I put in my code the property to True, the WordWrap is not activated : it DOESN'T work http://www.evolutiongraph.fr/chevereto/images/2015/02/16/CaptureqXAbm.jpg

Comment: Maybe if you set style options WordWrap is turned off. Check WordWrap after create manualy. `ShowMessage(BoolToStr(LItem.TextSettings.WordWarp))`

Comment: I realize that when I change other properties, they are not taken into account. For exemple `LItem.TextSettings.Font.Size:=19;` does not change anything :(

Comment: Look [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360778/how-to-adjust-listbox-items-height-to-fit-the-text-in-firemonkey-android) maybe you will find answer.

Comment: Nothing about WordWrap :(

Comment: After days and days of research, I still have found nothing ... if anyone has an idea ...